# Can't filter slicers after protecting pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to protect my pivot table which also uses slicers.

I have used the below code to unprotect the sheet refresh the pivot table and then protect again. I believe I have added all the criteria I need in order to be able to still use the slicers but this isn't the case. What am I missing?

```
Sub RefreshPivotTable()
'
' RefreshPivotTable Macro
'
    Dim DashboardSheet As Worksheet
    Set DashboardSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dashboard")
    DashboardSheet.Unprotect
    Range("C7").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Charger_Finder").PivotCache.Refresh
    DashboardSheet.Protect , DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something the following:

> STEP 1: Click on a Slicer, hold the CTRL key and select the other
>   Slicers
>
> STEP 2: Right click on a Slicer and select Size & Properties
>
> STEP 3: Under Position and Layout, "check" Disable resizing and moving
>
> STEP 4: Under Properties, “uncheck” the Locked box and press Close
>
> STEP 5: Go to the ribbon menu and select Review > Protect Sheet
>
> STEP 6: “Uncheck” the Select Locked Cells and “Check” the Select
>   Unlocked Cells & Use Pivot Table Reports
>
> STEP 7: Enter a password (optional) and press OK

After doing the above when you come to protecting your Sheet, it should leave the Slicer in a usable state.

However, a dedicated or incompetent user can still select and modify/delete the slicer.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to read this and help me! This has done the trick!

Comment: @AnaCastro, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks. :)